# Unable to delete React project folder & other issue with npm install and create-react-app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, windows

I uploaded my react project created in linux(because in Windows, create-react-app is stuck forever, that's an issue by itself), uploaded it to github, and then cloned the repo in my windows machine to further work on it. To my surprise, the `npm install` was stuck forever at a certain point(I need a solution to this as well), so I terminated the process, and now while deleting the project directory, it stucks at a specific point.  What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried `window.location.reload(false);`

Comment: no I haven't. Where should I do this?